# Error with the ZF tool while setting up the GuestBook Application

Tags: zend-framework

Iam trying to set up the GuestBook Application which comes with zend framework tutorial , Iam following the steps one by one,

However when I enter this command - zf create db-table Guestbook guestbook

Iam getting an error, I have pasted the error here -

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\quickstart>zf create db-table Guestbook guestbook  
               An Error Has Occurred  Provider 'db-table' is not a valid provider.
```

I tried googling and searching on zend forums, but seems no one got this sort of issue so far. Can anyone suggest me whats wrong here?

PS: I have set php in my system path and zf tool works for me, its only this specific command thats giving error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Lots of digging in and breaking my head with the ZF tool I found that it is using  copy of Zend framework which comes with Xampp for Windows.

When I installed Xampp, Zend Framework(Version 1.9.7) got installed inside the

C:\Xampp\Php\Pear\Zend

directory and since C:\Xampp\Php is in my system path this Zend framework got picked up everytime by Zend Tool.

I copied the latest version of stable Zend Framework(1.10.2) to the Zend folder inside Php\Pear and now its works like cake for me :)

Thanks for all your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Download latest version of framework files from this link **http://www.zend.com/community/downloads** & then extract zip file where you will get folder structure like **ZendFramework-1.11.12/library/Zend**, So from this folder copy Zend folder to  **Xampp/php/PEAR/zend** folder. Then Go to command mode type  **Zf --help**. Now it shows all the commands.

Now also check version of zend-framework in command mode by typing as

**zf show version**

it should show  as version as **zend Framework Version: 1.11.12**

Answer (score 0):

Check your version, maybe `db-table` is newer than your version. I just tried the same command you used (`zf create db-table Guestbook guestbook`) and it worked.

When i write `zf show version` it responds `1.11.0dev`. **What does your version say?** If it's low, consider updating after following the changelog and testing the rest of your application with the new version of zf.

Comment: Hi Zf show version shows 1.9.6 , I downloaded the latest version of zend framework 1.10.2 but when I run the zf.bat inside the bin folder it still says version 1.9.6 on command show version? Where Can I find the version 1.11.0dev which you have?

Comment: **Really** make sure the `zf` command points to the right zf.bat. Do this by renaming your old version of the library. If it fails then, it means it's still trying to use the old version. My version is a couple of days old, from framework.zend.com

Comment: Yep, did the same already but still same issue remains, it still shows 1.9.7 for framework 1.10.2

Comment: Can you upload your zend tool and zf.php somewhere from where I can download it, this is breaking my head now..

Comment: Hm, now I know why there might be a difference. My copy is from their SVN trunk, I checked it out from there. Can you try that?